# Split string with IFS using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, split, ifs

I have a string like:

```
Spain-South Africa:2-1
```

And I want to split it like:

```
Spain-South Africa
2-1
```

I have tried to split it by `IFS=':'` but it gives me:

```
Spain-South

Africa
2-1
```

My code:

[image: code]

Comment: `IFS` by itself does nothing; what command that *uses* `IFS` are you running to produce that output?

Comment: I read that string from a file,so I use this: read -r -a results <<< "$str"

Comment: And how are you displaying the contents of `results`?

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001); `str` is never set to the value you think it is in the first place, because the shell is splitting the output of `cat` on *whitespace*, not just newlines.

Comment: Type your code in the question; don't post links to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce, but you are probably either not setting `IFS` correctly for the `read` command, or you are not displaying the output correctly.

```
$ str="Spain-South Africa:2-1"
$ IFS=: read -ra results <<< "$str"
$ declare -p results
declare -a results=([0]="Spain-South Africa" [1]="2-1")
```

Based on your short-lived comment, you want something like

```
while IFS=: read -ra results; do
    ...
done < "$1"
```

rather than

```
for str in $(cat "$1"); do
    ...
done
```